# Can I use PBS environment variables inside the PBS directives of my script?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

Something like:

```
#PBS -t 0-99
#PBS -d "~/$PBS_ARRAYID.output"
```

What I want to do here is to redefine the working directory of each individual job in the job array, using the job's array id. Is this valid code?

I need to know before I send to the cluster, because I can't run tests there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use any of the environment variables listed [here](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm) in -d, -o, or -e.